# I am having a problem with reading a variable, comparing it and then printing the output while using loops

Tags: c++

I need to accept two numbers from the user and I need to compare those to a list of numbers they will enter after that.  Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int i = 1, count, num1, num2, num3, n;
bool check= false;

cout << "Please, enter the first number: ";
cin >> num1;
cout << "Please, enter your second number: ";
cin >> num2;
cout <<"-----------------------------"<<endl;
cout << "How many numbers you will enter? "<<endl;
cin >> count;

for (i; i<= count; i++)
{
    cout<<"Enter your #"<<i<<" number: ";
    do
    {
    cin >> num3;
    if (num1 == num3 && num2 == num3)
        {   
            n = 1;
            check = true;
        }
        else if (num1 == num3 && num2 != num3)
        {   
            n = 2;
            check = true;
        }
        else if (num1 != num3 && num2 == num3)
        {   
            n = 3;
            check = true;
        }
        else
        {
            n = 4;
            check = true;
        }
    }
    while (!check);
}
if (n == 1)
cout<<"Both "<<num1<<" and "<<num2<<" are found."<<endl;
else if (n == 2)
cout<<"Only the first number "<<num1<<" was found."<<endl;
else if (n == 3)
cout<<"Only the second number "<<num2<<" was found."<<endl;
else if (n == 4)
cout<<"Neither numbers "<<num1<<" and "<<num2<<" were found."<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

The problem here is it will never tell me if both of the numbers the user entered appeared in the list of numbers they entered.  I can get it to tell me if one or the other was entered but never both. How can I fix this so that if both number are found it will print that at the end?

Comment: Just a *guess*, but shouldn't you write the output inside the `for` loop? And then *reset* the `check` and `n` variables?

Comment: You set `check` to `true` in every situation, you can just set it to `true` on initialization and not to touch it. It is difficult to say what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program logic seems to be flawed, and even if it weren't, there is no point in over complicating this task. Here is a simpler approach:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int count, num1, num2, num3;

    cout << "Please, enter the first number: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Please, enter your second number: ";
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "-----------------------------" <<endl;
    cout << "How many numbers you will enter? " <<endl;
    cin >> count;

    bool if_1_in = false; // if the first seen
    bool if_2_in = false; // if the second seen

    for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter your #" << i+1 << " number: ";
        cin >> num3;
        if (!if_1_in || !if_2_in) { // if both are seen, we don't check anymore
            if (num1 == num3) // we set the flag if the first one is seen
            {   
                if_1_in = true;
            }
            if (num2 == num3) // we set the flag if the second one is seen
            {   
                if_2_in = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (if_1_in && if_2_in) // both are seen
    cout<<"Both "<<num1<<" and "<<num2<<" are found."<<endl;
    else if (if_1_in)       // just the first one is seen
    cout<<"Only the first number "<<num1<<" was found."<<endl;
    else if (if_2_in)       // just the second one is seen
    cout<<"Only the second number "<<num2<<" was found."<<endl;
    else                    // neither one is seen
    cout<<"Neither numbers "<<num1<<" and "<<num2<<" were found."<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
Please, enter the first number: 1
Please, enter your second number: 4
-----------------------------
How many numbers you will enter?
4
Enter your #1 number: 1
Enter your #2 number: 2
Enter your #3 number: 3
Enter your #4 number: 4
Both 1 and 4 are found.


Please, enter the first number: 1
Please, enter your second number: 4
-----------------------------
How many numbers you will enter?
4
Enter your #1 number: 1
Enter your #2 number: 2
Enter your #3 number: 3
Enter your #4 number: 5
Only the first number 1 was found.


Please, enter the first number: 1
Please, enter your second number: 4
-----------------------------
How many numbers you will enter?
4
Enter your #1 number: 2
Enter your #2 number: 3
Enter your #3 number: 4
Enter your #4 number: 5
Only the second number 4 was found.


Please, enter the first number: 1
Please, enter your second number: 4
-----------------------------
How many numbers you will enter?
4
Enter your #1 number: 2
Enter your #2 number: 3
Enter your #3 number: 5
Enter your #4 number: 6
Neither numbers 1 and 4 were found.
```

You may even use `std::unordered_set` to make this program useful for a more general case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int count, num1, num2, num3;

    cout << "Please, enter the first number: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Please, enter your second number: ";
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "-----------------------------" <<endl;
    cout << "How many numbers you will enter? " <<endl;
    cin >> count;

    std::unordered_set<int> seen;

    for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter your #" << i+1 << " number: ";
        cin >> num3;
        seen.insert(num3);
    }
    if (seen.find(num1) != seen.end() && seen.find(num2) != seen.end()) // both are seen
    cout << "Both " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " are found." <<endl;
    else if (seen.find(num1) != seen.end())                             // just the first one is seen
    cout << "Only the first number " << num1 << " was found." << endl;
    else if (seen.find(num2) != seen.end())                             // just the second one is seen
    cout << "Only the second number " << num2 << " was found." << endl;
    else                                                                // neither one is seen
    cout << "Neither numbers " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " were found." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can understand now why my logic was not that good.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you keep resetting `n` when you find a number that doesn't match `num1` or `num2`.  If you enter `5` and `10` for the numbers to find and the enter `5` and `1` as the numbers to compare against you'll find `5`, set `n` to `2` and then when you check `1`, it doesn't match so you set `n` to `4`.  What you need is two `bool` variables, one for if you find `num1` and another for if you find `num2`.

You also don't need the `do..while` loop.  It doesn't do anything as you only ever loop a single time.  Making the above two changes the code can be condensed to

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int i = 1, count, num1, num2, num3;
    bool found1 = false, found2 = false;

    cout << "Please, enter the first number: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Please, enter your second number: ";
    cin >> num2;
    cout <<"-----------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << "How many numbers you will enter? "<<endl;
    cin >> count;

    for (; i<= count; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter your #"<<i<<" number: ";
        cin >> num3;
        if (num3 == num1)
            found1 = true;
        if (num3 == num2)
            found2 = true;
    }
    if (found1 && found2)
        cout<<"Both "<<num1<<" and "<<num2<<" are found."<<endl;
    else if (found1)
        cout<<"Only the first number "<<num1<<" was found."<<endl;
    else if (found2)
        cout<<"Only the second number "<<num2<<" was found."<<endl;
    else 
        cout<<"Neither numbers "<<num1<<" and "<<num2<<" were found."<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

You should also get into the habit of writting for loops like

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
```

instead of

```
for (; i<= count; i++)
```

The first case is the "standard" loop as it is how you would access an array since arrays are 0 indexed.  It also keeps `i` scoped to the for loop and since it isn't needed outside the loop that is where it should be.  You want to keep your variables as local as they can be so you don't clutter up your scopes with unneeded variables.

Comment: This code has the same behavior of my code. It will only compare the last value of num3 to my two first numbers. I want to compare all the entered values of num3 to my two numbers.

Comment: @Mohammed This will check all of the number.  If you enter `10` and `5` for `num1` and `num2`, `4` for `count` an then `1`, `2`, `10`, `5` it will say it found both numbers: https://wandbox.org/permlink/0kySZPZI6GJ580q5

Comment: @Mohammed This is what the two different `bool` variables are for.  If we ever see a `num3` that matches `num1` then we set `found1` to `true`.  We never unset it so at the end of the loop if `found1` is `true` we know at some point `num3` matched `num1`.  The same thing happens for `num2`.  We only need to remember if we found the number, which this does.

Answer (score -5):

in the for loop:

`for(i=0; i<=count; i++)`

also, get rid of the `do{}while()` loop since it's always executed once

all tests (`if(n==x)`) must be in the for loop

Comment: `i` initialized when declared, it could be not the best style but it is not the error either. And OP initialized it to proper value to make `count` iterations. Yes it would be better to make it zero based but then you need to fix condition as well.